# Property 'Circle' does not exist on type 'typeof Draw'

Tags: angular, import, leaflet

I get this error :

```
Property 'Circle' does not exist on type 'typeof Draw'
```

when I try to use :

```
var circleDrawer = new L.Draw.Circle();
```

I thought the imports were good with :

```
import 'leaflet-draw';
```

Did I miss something ? Here is my package.json file :

```
...
"dependencies": {
"@types/proj4leaflet": "^1.0.4",
"leaflet": "1.0.3",
"leaflet-circle-to-polygon": "1.0.0",
"leaflet-draw": "0.4.10",
"leaflet-map": "0.2.1",
"leaflet-measure": "2.1.7",
"leaflet-popup-angular": "^1.0.3",
"leaflet-virtual-grid": "1.0.4",
"leaflet.vectorgrid": "1.2.0",
"proj4leaflet": "^1.0.2",
...      
},
"devDependencies": {
"@types/leaflet": "1.0.67",
"@types/leaflet-draw": "0.4.6",
...
}
```

Comment: What is "L" in your ts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this line.

```
declare const L: any;
```

I believe you forgot to do this.

Comment: Actually I imported "L.Layer" instead of simply declaring L. Thank you for the answer.